# How to find CSS element with specific tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, css-selectors, capybara, integration-testing

This is my inspect element snippet:

```
<div>
  <map>
    <area href="javascript:void(0)" log="miw" ... shape="poly" title="lender_marker test@example.com">
    <area href="javascript:void(0)" log="miw" ... shape="poly" title="lender_marker othertest@example.com">
  </map>
</div>
```

The `...` represents a bunch of other tags that I won't include. FYI these elements are from Google Maps API V3 in JS, and I'm using this [great tutorial](http://blog.mojotech.com/selecting-google-maps-v3-markers-with-selenium-or-jquery/) to try to test, except the tutorial works in Selenium and I'd like to use Capybara/ Rspec. Also, used [this post](http://www.natontesting.com/2011/09/24/css-locator-referencecheat-sheet-for-xpath-people/) to formulate the selectors in the first place.

**I need to do two things in my integration tests:**

1. Count # of `lender_marker` regardless of email
2. Click on `lender_marker` with a specific email

For #1...

- While I'd love to count just the `lender_markers` regardless of email, I figure if I can't even find the `lender_marker test@example.com` I won't worry about finding just `lender_marker`, hence the tests as they're written below
- Also the variations layer, so I've tried every possible permutation of the below

Trials:

```
#Base test
page.should have_selector("area[title='lender_marker test@example.com']")

#First variation: change selector statement
page.assert_selector("area[title='lender_marker test@example.com']")

#Second variation: no quotes
page.should have_selector(area[title='lender_marker test@example.com'])

#Third variation: use map 
page.should have_selector("map[title='lender_marker test@example.com']")

#Fourth variation: use div 
page.should have_selector("div[title='lender_marker test@example.com']")
```

For #2, I can't even try it until I've first off been able to locate the area object, but I can't...

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your CSS-selector, which leads me to believe it is a visibility issue. The tutorial you reference is using `find_elements`, which in Selenium will find all elements matching the selector. In contrast, when Capybara looks for elements it only returns elements that match the selector **and** are determined to be visible to the user.

In other words, I am guessing that the area elements exist but Capybara does not think they are visible. You likely need to trigger something to make the areas become visible.

However, you can validate that the elements exist, regardless of visibility, by using the `:visible` option:

```
# Validate that a specific area exists in the DOM
page.should have_selector('area[title="lender_marker test@example.com"]', visible: false)

# Count the number of lender_markers
page.all('area[title^="lender_marker"]', visible: false).length
#=> 2

# Count the number of lender_markers with minimum in case of async loading
puts page.all('area[title^="lender_marker"]', visible: false, minimum: 2).length
#=> 2

# Validate the number of lender_markers
page.should have_selector('area[title^="lender_marker"]', visible: false, count: 2)
```

Comment: thanks! that provided great insight so I checked out what was going on with a `save_and_open_page`. You're totally correct on the not visible, but in this case, it's not even loading because the Google API doesn't want to load in the test server... I had this issue on my local server as well but solved it by enabling CORS with `config.action_dispatch.default_headers.merge!({
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' => '*',
      'Access-Control-Request-Method' => '*'
    })` in the `application.rb` but I guess this doesn't extend to test server... Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, I have not worked with the Google API and so do not have any insights there.